# I don't have Layout Editor Android Studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I searched and learned that Layout editor is under the res file but there is only drawable file under res file.I tried right click to a xml file and open with but it's not working.I am using windows 8.1 pro.
I tried to go->View->Window Tools->Preview(missing too) I don't have preview in Window Tools

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing in the IDE?

Comment: ok .................

Comment: under app there is  src file and under src file there is main file. res file is under main

Comment: under res file there must be drawable and layout but I don't have layout

Comment: have you created an activity or fragment yet with a corresponding layout? Some of the res folders are not being created before they're actually needed.

Comment: Why you are not using Android Studio?

Comment: I am using Android Studio

Comment: Have you created any activity?

Comment: I think you don't have any layouts to show. That's why it is not showing in layout folder. Go to src >main >java   then there will be your package. Then right click and select  new>Activity>Empty Activity

Comment: Okey I searched it.Yes I already created empty activity

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Go to View -> Tool Windows -> Preview
```

Also try

```
Go to File -> invalidate cache / restart
```

Comment: there is no Preview in tool windows

Comment: try Go to File -> invalidate cache / restart , if this not solve your problem please share build.gradle file. you may be need to downgrade/change in dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The Layout Editor is only for layout .xml files. You have to create a layout .xml file under the /res/layout resource directory and double-click to edit that file before seeing the Layout Editor.

**Note:** *Preview* like in vinay's answer is only for drawable .xml files, and they show a blank screen unless you've drawn shapes (defined by the `<item></item>` tags).